# It's possible open multiple connections to multiple sites using only one thread?

Tags: java, http, connection, web-crawler

### Update

I use a `FixedThreadPool` already. What happens is that each thread open one connection for one site. What I want to do is something asynchronous.

1. Send request to a server
2. Go to next request without need to wait the first request to complete
3. When a request was established, do something informing another thread that connection was established and ready for download.

I think this will speed up the execution because will use less threads for opening the same or more connection that the currently performance.

In the current way, each thread wait a time without work waiting the connection establishes. In this new way, it will be always working.

---

### The Question

I want to know if there is a way to open connection to multiple sites with only one thread.

This is because I'm doing an webcrawler, I already did a thread to open a connection, but after a certain number of threads, this will not help because the processor sharing will increase a lot.

I want this to speed up the number of pages downloaded. It's possible do this? How?

**This code open a connection and do some processing. It's executed by the threads that open a connection**

```
/*
 * Open connection to a server
 */
boolean openConnection(Link link) throws Exception {
    //set the connection paramenters
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(link.getOriginalURL().getURL()).openConnection();
    conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", ROBOT_NAME);
    conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
    conn.setConnectTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
    conn.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
    link.setConnection(conn);
    //open the connection
    conn.connect();        
    //check the server answer
    if (conn.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
        return false;
    }
    //analyse the URL of the redirected URL
    urlAnalyzer.fillURL(link.getRedirectedURL(), getRedirectedURL(link.getConnection()));
    return true;
}
```

**This executes the connection openers, each one in one thread**

```
/*
 * Start the execution of the connection openers     
 */
private void executeConnectionOpeners() {
    LOGGER.info("Starting connection openners.");
    /* Execution */
    NameThreadFactory ntf = new NameThreadFactory("Connection Opener");
    crawlerOpenerExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(nOpeners, ntf);
    for (int i = 0; i < nOpeners; i++) {
        crawlerOpenerExecutor.submit(new ConnectionOpener(this));
    }
    /* End of execution */
    LOGGER.info(nOpeners + " connection openers created and running.");
}
```

Comment: Why not use a fixed-size Thread pool?

Comment: Share your crawler Thread code block, and the community can provide better feedback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fetching web pages isn't a particularly processor-intensive job: you've going to spend almost all of your time waiting for the network unless you're fetching a lot of small pages from very fast local connections.

Of course, you should look at how many threads it's *actually* worth using, via benchmarking - you'll probably want to have a fixed set of threads working off a shared producer/consumer queue. (You don't want to create a genuine new thread for each request.)

Now it should be *possible* to use only a very few threads if you can perform the fetch asynchronously (potentially with NIO) but I would personally check whether the "separate threads" approach is *actually* maxing out your CPU first. It's probably going to make the code *much* simpler than using asynchrony, and if the bottleneck is really the network, then you'll end up with harder-to-maintain code for little (if any) benefit.

Answer (score 1):

Check out and see if you like Java 7's `AsynchronousSocketChannel`. Basically, you issue a read request, and when bytes are available, it'll call your callback. Of course, the callback must be invoked on some thread; you have some options to config the threading policy.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [xlightweb](http://xlightweb.org/) for similar purpose, i.e. **asynchronous HTTP**.